# Writing and changing code at runtime

Tags: c#, code-generation, reflection.emit, codedom, roslyn

I have a situation where I'd like to build MVC style views at runtime using their EditorFor/DisplayFor templates (or something similar).

Ideally our application would let the user choose which fields they want in their UI (so they can add /remove any as they see fit), to this end I thinking it'd be handy to be create viewmodel classess at runtime and add the various dataannotation attributes to them according to what user selects (ie. stringlength, required etc).

One thing I need to be able to support is changing of the generated classes at runtime without affecting other users or having to do a full iisreset.

To go about this I've been doing a bit of research and it seems like there might be 3 different approaches, CodeDom, RunSharp / Relfection.Emit,Roslyn.

From what I can tell reflection.Emit/Runsharp would allow me to create the classes and add attibutes and properties to them at runtime and probably also modify them when I need to without adverse effects.

I'm not sure if Roslyn would allow this, I haven't been able to track down any simple examples of creating a class with properties or attributes in it, and I've seen a few mentions that Roslyn's output is immutable so I'm not sure how that goes for allowing me to modify it at a later date without adverse effects.

In general from what I've seen most people don't recommend CodeDom so I'm not entirely sure if I should bother going down that route.

Can anyone give me an idea of which of these directions might be viable for me?

Comment: Are you sure you actually need to create a type at runtime? Wouldn't something like `Dictionary<string, object>` suffice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, none of these solutions are going to work, and honestly, generating type at runtime really isn't what you want here.

When it comes to the CLR, once you have a type with fields and methods, you can't really add new members or change members at runtime. The closest we come to doing that is the edit-and-continue features in Visual Studio, we're highly restricted to what changes we can make. We often 'cheat' by not adding methods or attributes where you think they added, but we hide them somewhere else and emit IL that references this secret location when you make an edit. Crazy things like removing members is entirely unsupported. Even if it *was* supported, lots of code likes to presume that doing `someObject.GetType().GetMembers()` returns the same thing over and over again.

As far as Roslyn is concerned, when we say the results are "immutable" we don't mean that puts any requirement on any IL that you might generate with it. Rather, when you ask Roslyn to parse something or analyze source code, the objects (syntax trees, type information, etc) is immutable. Still, it doesn't matter since you can't modify types in the CLR once they exist.

I'm with svick in his comment -- this isn't what you want to do. Use some appropriate data structures to represent your information at runtime, rather than trying to think of this as a concrete class that can be mutated somehow.

Comment: intersesting, yeah as I've been doing more research it was beginning to think this, if we didnt require the user to be able to change the types at runtime then I'd just have my own prebuilt classes in the code, so my idea was to try and reproduce that as much as possible by creating the entire classes dynamically, and then I could make use of things like MVCs reflection over objects for templates, and use RavenDB to store them without much modification

Comment: If you need the dynamic stuff, just use Dictionary<string, Whatever> in your types and don't worry about type safety in the traditional sense.

Comment: yeah I think I'm going with the a Class that has a Key (string) property and Value property (object), mainly due to some issues with dictionary bindings in MVC, I realised that I don't really care what the type is as long as I can tell it via reflection which I can with this approach